# SQL select statement similar to vertical search approximate match in Excel

Tags: sql, exact-online, invantive-sql

Having a table with columns 'price' and 'quantity'.

e.g:

```
rec  price   qty
1.   10,00     1
2.    7,50     5
3.    5,00    25
4.    3,00   100
```

I need to select the price for a quantity of 65. This is the price of record 3. Qty 65 is between qty 25 and 100. How to solve this in a sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that with an inner SQL statement which tries to find the highest quantity lower than or equal to your requested quantity of 65:

```
select pce.price
from   prices pce
join   ( select max(qty) qty
         from   prices
         where  qty <= 65
       ) pce2
on     pce.qty = pce2.qty
```

Here `pce2` is the join to match the `prices` line. The `pce` table is joined to have access to all fields joined. This will only work correctly if there are no duplicates in `prices` for `qty`.